# Update existing Tax Rates

Tags: tax

Magento's Tax Rate import utility creates a new rate (a duplicate) instead of updating existing rate. We need it to update existing rates.

Has anyone found a way of mass updating tax rates?

Comment: Figured it out. From phpMyAdmin I exported out the table "tax_calculation_rate" to .CSV file, applied the new tax rates using Excel and using phpMyAdmin imported the file. The values where successfully updated.